# What functions are continuous in the Michael line?

Tags: general-topology

The Michael line is given by the basis $B=\tau \cup \{\{x\}| x \in (\mathbb{R}-\mathbb{Q})\}$ where $\tau$ is the usual topology on $\mathbb{R}$. The Michael line has more open sets than the usual topology on $\mathbb{R}$, so I know that any functions that are continuous in the usual topology are also continuous in the Michael line. Which other functions are continuous in the Michael line?

Comment: Please include the definition of the Michael line for completeness.  How about a constant function other than at $\pi$?

Comment: @MichaelBurr I would've expected you of all people to know.

Comment: @Reveillark: Judging by the second half of his comment, I expect that he did.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I know, I just couldn't resist the silly joke.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\tau$ be the usual topology on $\Bbb R$, and let $\tau_M$ be the Michael line topology. Let $\Bbb P=\Bbb R\setminus\Bbb Q$. Let $X$ be any space, and let $f:\Bbb R\to X$. Each $x\in\Bbb P$ is isolated in $\tau_M$, so $f$ is automatically $\tau_M$ continuous at each $x\in\Bbb P$, and it’s easy to check that $f$ is $\tau_M$-continuous at a point $x\in\Bbb Q$ if and only if it is $\tau$-continuous at $x$, so we can conclude that $f$ is $\tau_M$-continuous if and only if it is $\tau$-continuous at each rational.

In particular, let $f:\Bbb R\to X$ be $\tau$-continuous, and let $F$ be a $\tau$-closed subset of $\Bbb P$. Then every function $g:\Bbb R\to X$ such that $$g\upharpoonright(\Bbb R\setminus F)=f\upharpoonright(\Bbb R\setminus F)$$ is $\tau_M$-continuous.